# Confusion about UseMethod search mechanism

Tags: r, dispatch

I'm trying to figure out how R's `UseMethod` finds a method once it figures out what its looking for (i.e. function MyGeneric( x ) called with x of class MyClass: MyGeneric.MyClass)
Specifically, what environments are involved?

I have read section "5.3 Method Dispatching" and "5.4 UseMethod" of the R Language Manual which does not specify the search mechanism.  The R-Help page for `UseMethod` provides a clue:

```
...UseMethod and NextMethod search for methods in two places: 
first in the environment in which the generic function is called, 
and then in the registration data base for the environment 
in which the generic is defined (typically a namespace)
```

But this doesn't add up (in my head =).  Here's a concrete example:

```
library( xts )
as.matrix  # shows UseMethod("as.matrix")
methods("as.matrix") # shows as.matrix.xts.  * indicates non-visible
showMethods("as.matrix")  # says <not an S4 generic function>
data(sample_matrix)
as.matrix( as.xts(sample_matrix) ) # how does R find as.matrix.xts??  its not exported!
```

`as.matrix` is defined in `namespace:base`.  If R were to use that environment, or the calling environment (R_GlobalEnv), it could not find `as.matrix.xts` because its not exported.  The calling environment would seem to work if a function within xts calls `as.matrix` because `as.matrix.xts` would be in the calling environment.  What am I missing?

Comment: This might be of help as well (both to the immediate question and generally understanding that part of the R Language Manual): http://obeautifulcode.com/R/How-R-Searches-And-Finds-Stuff/

Comment: mweylandt - funny enough, that's my blog post =)  Seems I need to add a section about generic functions/methods which deviates from the usual search/find mechanism.  Its a bit frustrating how complicated this stuff is in R.

Comment: it's a small world I suppose ;-) I'll leave it for anyone else who stumbles across this if you don't object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not reading that quite carefully enough.  It says the "registration database" is stored in the environment (namespace) of the generic, not the method itself.  In the case of `base::as.matrix`:

```
> grep("as.matrix",ls(base:::.__S3MethodsTable__.), value=TRUE)
[1] "as.matrix.dist"   "as.matrix.raster" "as.matrix.xts"    "as.matrix.zoo"
```

Comment: cool!  Does this depend on xts being attached versus loaded?  So if xts is listed in MyPackage's Imports, and I attach MyPackage (so xts is not in search()), then is as.matrix still stored in the environment of the generic?

Comment: @SFun28: that depends whether registration occurs during namespace loading or during attachment to the search path.  I don't know which is the case.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Joshua's insight which added to my knowledge .... Being in a loaded NAMESPACE is not the same as being exported. You could have seen the as.matrix.xts function with either of these:

```
 getAnywhere(as.matrix.xts)
 xts:::as.matrix.xts
```

Try typing

```
search()
```

I have also seen on either SO or rhelp a function that would display the the R interpreter's search path for a function call, but at the moment I cannot seem to find it. This produces a rather long list of function names:

```
apropos("as", mode="function")
```

And this list was still half a long:

```
apropos("^as\\.", mode="function")
```

Comment: Its good to know about getAnywhere(), that's new to me.  Its fairly easy to list the search path of as.matrix.xts (see stackoverflow.com/questions/8637107/parent-env-x-confusion) but I haven't seen a function that tells you how R gets to any given non-exported function. If you can dig that up it would be really useful.

Comment: The triple-dot operator is the strongest search method that I know. It doesn't require that a function be loaded, only that it can be found in an installed package on your library paths.