# R generic dispatching to attached environment

Tags: r, r-s3

I have a bunch of functions and I'm trying to keep my workspace clean by defining them in an environment and attaching the environment. Some of the functions are S3 generics, and they don't seem to play well with this approach.

A minimum example of what I'm experiencing requires 4 files:

testfun.R

```
ttt.xxx <- function(object) print("x")

ttt <- function(object) UseMethod("ttt")

ttt2 <- function() {
  yyy <- structure(1, class="xxx")
  ttt(yyy)
}
```

In testfun.R I define an S3 generic ttt and a method ttt.xxx, I also define a function ttt2 calling the generic.

testenv.R

```
test_env <- new.env(parent=globalenv()) 
source("testfun.R", local=test_env) 
attach(test_env)
```

In testenv.R I source testfun.R to an environment, which I attach.

test1.R

```
source("testfun.R")
ttt2()
xxx <- structure(1, class="xxx")
ttt(xxx)
```

test1.R sources testfun.R to the global environment. Both ttt2 and a direct function call work.

test2.R

```
source("testenv.R")
ttt2()
xxx <- structure(1, class="xxx")
ttt(xxx)
```

test2.R uses the "attach" approach. ttt2 still works (and prints "x" to the console), but the direct function call fails:

```
Error in UseMethod("ttt") : 
  no applicable method for 'ttt' applied to an object of class "xxx"
```

however, calling ttt and ttt.xxx without arguments show that they are known, ls(pos=2) shows they are on the search path, and sloop::s3_dispatch(ttt(xxx)) tells me it should work.

This questions is related to [Confusion about UseMethod search mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518901/confusion-about-usemethod-search-mechanism) and the link therein https://blog.thatbuthow.com/how-r-searches-and-finds-stuff/, but I cannot get my head around what is going on: why is it not working and how can I get this to work.

I've tried both R Studio and R in the shell.

UPDATE:
Based on the answers below I changed my testenv.R to:

```
test_env <- new.env(parent=globalenv()) 
source("testfun.R", local=test_env) 
attach(test_env)
if (is.null(.__S3MethodsTable__.))
  .__S3MethodsTable__. <- new.env(parent = baseenv())
for (func in grep(".", ls(envir = test_env), fixed = TRUE, value = TRUE))
  .__S3MethodsTable__.[[func]] <- test_env[[func]]
rm(test_env, func)
```

... and this works (I am only using "." as an S3 dispatching separator).

Comment: The problem you are trying to solved is solved rigorously by the module system of [the ‘box’ package](https://klmr.me/box/). Give it a try!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s a little-known fact that **you must use [`.S3method()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/S3method.html) to define methods for S3 generics** inside custom environments (outside of packages).<sup>1</sup> The reason almost nobody knows this is because it is *not* necessary in the global environment; but it is necessary everywhere else since R version 3.6.

There’s virtually no documentation of this change, just [a technical blog post by Kurt Hornik about some of the background](https://blog.r-project.org/2019/08/19/s3-method-lookup/). Note that the blog post says the change was made in R 3.5.0; however, the actual effect you are observing — that S3 methods are no longer searched in attached environments — only started happening with R 3.6.0; before that, it was somehow not active yet.

… except just using `.S3method` will *not* fix your code, since your *calling environment* is the global environment. I do not understand the precise reason why this doesn’t work, and I suspect it’s due to a subtle bug in R’s S3 method lookup. In fact, using `getS3method('ttt', 'xxx')` *does* work, even though that should have the same behaviour as actual S3 method lookup.

I have found that the only way to make this work is to add the following to `testenv.R`:

```
if (is.null(.__S3MethodsTable__.)) {
    .__S3MethodsTable__. <- new.env(parent = baseenv())
}

.__S3MethodsTable__.$ttt.xxx <- ttt.xxx
```

… in other words: supply `.GlobalEnv` manually with an S3 methods lookup table. Unfortunately this relies on an undocumented S3 implementation detail that might theoretically change in the future.

Alternatively, it “just works” if you use [‘box’ modules](https://klmr.me/box/articles/box.html) instead of `source`. That is, you can replace the entirety of your `testenv.R` by the following:

```
box::use(./testfun[...])
```

This code treats `testfun.R` as a *local module* and loads it, attaching all exported names (via the attach declaration `[...]`).

---

<sup>1</sup> (and inside packages you need to use the equivalent `S3method` namespace declaration, though if you’re using ‘roxygen2’ then that’s taken care of for you)

Comment: I was so close... I had actually tried .S3method(), both in the local and the global environment. I wasn't using "box" since I didn't know about it, but also since I wanted to keep my code "package-free". Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

First of all, my advice would be:  don't try to reinvent R packages.  They solve all the problems you say you are trying to solve, and others as well.

Secondly, I'll try to explain what went wrong in `test2.R`.  It calls `ttt` on an `xxx` object, and `ttt.xxx` is on the search list, but is not found.

The problem is how the search for `ttt.xxx` happens.  The search *doesn't* look for `ttt.xxx` in the search list, it looks for it in the environment from which `ttt` was called, then in an object called `.__S3MethodsTable__.`.  I think there are two reasons for this:

- First, it's a lot faster.  It only needs to look in one or two places, and the table can be updated whenever a package is attached or detached, a relatively rare operation.
- Second, it's more reliable.  Each package has its own methods table, because two packages can use the same name for generics that have nothing to do with each other, or can use the same class names that are unrelated.  So package code needs to be able to count on finding its own definitions first.

Since your call to `ttt()` happens at the top level, that's where R looks first for `ttt.xxx()`, but it's not there.  Then it looks in the global `.__S3MethodsTable__.` (which is actually in the base environment), and it's not there either.  So it fails.

There is a workaround that will make your code work.  If you run

```
.__S3MethodsTable__. <- list2env(list(ttt.xxx = ttt.xxx))
```

as the last line of testenv.R, then you'll create a methods table in the global environment.  (Normally there isn't one there, because that's user space, and R doesn't like putting things there unless the user asks for it.)
R will find that methods table, and will find the `ttt.xxx` method that it defines.  I wouldn't be surprised if this breaks some other aspect of S3 dispatch, so I don't recommend doing it, but give it a try if you insist on reinventing the package system.

Comment: Thank you very much. Not accepting your answer because @konrad-rudolph's is a bit more complete.

Comment: No problem, though I'd avoid `box`:  put your code in a package.