# `sys.source` and S3 methods

Tags: r

I have an issue with S3 methods when sourcing files using `sys.source`.

Assume dummy S3 generic and method

```
# dummy.r
dummy = function(x, ...) UseMethod("dummy")

dummy.data.frame = function(x, ...) print(x)
```

Normally, simply `attach`-ing a new environment would work, but the documentation says that a copy of the environment is attached instead, which isn't updated. Instead, the canonical way that is in `sys.source` suggests:

```
.sourced_code = attach(NULL, name = ".sourced_code")

sys.source("dummy.r", .sourced_code)
```

Now, `search()` will show `.sourced_code` in the search path, and both `dummy()` and `dummy.data.frame()` can be reached. However,  `dummy(iris)` says that there is no method for `dummy` applied on object `data.frame`.

That is fine, we know how to solve it, or do we?

Normally, `.S3method()`, or the underlying function `registerS3method()` would do the trick since the only time when S3 method do not need to be explicitly registered is when they are all in the same environment (i.e., typically in the user's baseenv after `source` or when defined in console).

Sadly, `.S3method()` doesn't work for some reason and by this point, I am too confused about what is going on. The `.__S3MethodTable__.` is created in the `.sourced_code` environment, `methods(dummy)` do find the `dummy.data.frame` method, but dispatch is still confused.

Can we figure it out?

**edit:**

The answer stated by @the-mad-statter works for a slightly different definition of the problem, but not for the problem itself.

```
.sourced_code = attach(NULL, name = ".sourced_code")
sys.source("dummy.r", .sourced_code)

if (is.null(.__S3MethodsTable__.)) {
  .__S3MethodsTable__. <- new.env(parent = baseenv())
}

.__S3MethodsTable__.$dummy.data.frame <- dummy.data.frame

dummy(iris)
```

Fails :( The difference is the way `attach` is called. The ability to source more code to the same environment without having to re-attach it is crucial, and the code itself is canonical since it is in `sys.source` help page.

Answer (score 1):

This question is similar to but a tiny bit more complicated than this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74841613/r-generic-dispatching-to-attached-environment). The main complication arises due to the need to source into the environment before attaching which differs from the example in `?sys.source`

I think [@user2554330](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2554330/user2554330) summarizes the main issue well. Here is an abbreviated version applying to your question:

> The problem is how the search for `dummy.data.frame` happens. The search doesn't look for `dummy.data.frame` in the search list, it looks for it in the environment from which `dummy` was called, then in an object called `.__S3MethodsTable__.`.

> Since your call to `dummy()` happens at the top level, that's where R looks first for `dummy.data.frame()`, but it's not there. Then it looks in the global `.__S3MethodsTable__.` (which is actually in the base environment), and it's not there either. So it fails.

Here is how you might work around this issue based on information in the other question:

```r
# as child of global to pick up functions like `<-` when sourcing
.sourced_code <- new.env(parent=globalenv())

# source into the new environment
sys.source("dummy.R", .sourced_code)

# attach after sourcing since "a copy of the environment is attached instead, which isn't updated"
attach(.sourced_code)

# begin Konrad's suggested code
if (is.null(.__S3MethodsTable__.)) {
  .__S3MethodsTable__. <- new.env(parent = baseenv())
}

.__S3MethodsTable__.$dummy.data.frame <- dummy.data.frame
# end Konrad's suggested code

# test
dummy(iris)
#>     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
#> 1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
#> 2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa
#> 3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa
#> 4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa
#> 5            5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     setosa
...
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I am upvoting the answer, but I cannot accept it. While your answer works for the problem stated in your answer, it doesn't work for the problem stated in my question. The critical difference being the interaction between `attach` and `sys.source`. Notably, you are registering only a copy of environment, while I was interested in an active modifiable environment. Stated answer doesn't work there.

Comment: Ok. Interestingly `with(.sourced_code, dummy(iris))` works in your original example.